# Why is Safari changing the width of these off-canvas elements?

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm getting strange behaviour occurring in Safari on OSX and more noticeably on iOS with this CSS driven radiobox multi-select form I'm working on...

http://s.codepen.io/achisholm/debug/jPzzzB

Same page with editors visible...
http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/jPzzzB?editors=110

During the .3s transition, notice the width of the `multi-form__option-content` element seems to go from 0 to 100% while opening and closing.

It doesn't happen on any other browser, only Safari. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `transition: all .3s ease;` to `transition: height .3s ease;`

```
  &__option-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .3s ease; /*this one*/
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0px 50px;
    line-height: 1.6;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwVXNb